# Class "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller" not found while loading "App\Controller\StudentController"

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.2

Hi I'm fresher for symfony . when i execute the below code it will show error.i installed all the assets of symfony.help me to clear this..!

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class StudentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //  return new Response(
        //   '<html><body><h1>HI,Welcome to Tamilnadu</h1></body></html>'
        // );
        return $this->render('student/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

I just put "hello" in (student/index.html.twig),and i commented the basic response function and want to run the return this function.

Comment: How did you install symfony? Did you try it before changes the Response?

Comment: @GrenierJ Thank you sir..       i just install it from symfony documentation site.At first i got a output for this return new Response(),when i moved to render method got error

Comment: @ramsurathkumar-s 
You probably have symfony version 5. You need to inherit the AbstractController class instead of Controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="index")
 * @return Response
 */
public function index():Response{
    return $this->render('student/index.html.twig');
}
```